# Send file over TCP with additional meta data

Tags: node.js, tcp, stream, server

I'm sending a file over TCP to a server that pipes the stream into a file.

The client is just piping a readable stream to the network connection.

I want to send the file ID as well with the file. What are my options?

- should I implement a handshake protocol to get the meta data before sending the file?
- should I send a fixed block size as headers for the meta data before sending the file? If so, how do I rewind the stream if I get too much data passed the headers?

Thank you!

Comment: `[...] how do I rewind the stream if I get too much data passed the headers?`
Why would you need to do that ?
Both solutions sounds OK to me, but I prefer the handshake one, as it let you some time to initialize things before reading the rest of the stream.

Comment: @Maxime let's say the headers are 256k long and the first packet that arrives is 512k long.. I can't just pipe anymore the stream to a file easily.

Comment: Don't use TCP. Use a higher-level protocol such as HTTP.

Comment: @usr I guess you are right. I could send the meta data as parameters and stream the body content to a file very easily. Do you mind posting this as an answer? I will select this as an accepted answer. Thanks !

Comment: I recently have had to send PDFs over `TCP` to push them to a printing service. The client needs data for tracking/instructions to get sent with the "job". We ended up writing this metadata to the PDF's metadata during PDF construction, then once things are on the other side, they parse the PDFs metadata, extract `UUID` etc., and send us a success response over `HTTP` to a dedicated endpoint. cludgy, but it was our only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use TCP. Use a higher-level protocol such as HTTP. Send the meta data as HTTP headers.